# Invoke a Method of Child form opened with Using Statement

Tags: c#, reflection, using-statement

I am trying to figure out how to invoke a method of a child form which is opened in a using block.

In my code, I have a MainForm which is a MDI parent. MDI parent holds a reference of parent form . A parent form where the below method is declared.

1. The ParentForm Instance is available in MDIParent form as shown in the following code.

   **MainForm.cs**

   ```
    private void OpenParentForm()
    {
        try
        {

            FormParent frmParent = null;
            frmParent = Application.OpenForms["frmParent"] as FormParent;

            if (frmParent != null)
            {
                frmParent.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                frmParent = new FormParent();
                frmParent.Name = "frmParent";
                frmParent.MdiParent = this;
                frmParent.Show();
            }

        }
        catch { }
    }
   ```
2. The Child form is opened in

   **frmParent.cs**

   ```
    private void ShowChildForm()
    {
        try
        {
            using (ChildForm frmChild = new ChildForm())
            {

                if (frmChild.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    this.RefreshData();

                frmChild.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
   ```

The ChildForm having following method.

**ChildForm.cs**

```
private void ChildMethod()
{
    //........
    //........
    //........
}
```

Following is my InvokeMethod

**ReflectionHelper.cs**

```
public static async Task<bool> InvokeMethod(Form Window, string methodName, object param)
{
    try
    {
        Form mainWindow = Window;
        var MainWindowtype = mainWindow.GetType();
        MethodInfo MethodtoInvoke = MainWindowtype.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (MethodtoInvoke != null)
        {
            ParameterInfo[] pars = MethodtoInvoke.GetParameters();
            object[] Parameter = null;

            try
            {
                object returnValue = null;
                if (pars != null && pars.Length > 0)
                {
                    Parameter = new object[pars.Length];
                    foreach (var item in pars)
                    {
                        int index = item.Position;
                        if (param != null)
                        {
                            if (param.GetType() == item.ParameterType || item.ParameterType == typeof(object))
                            {
                                Parameter[index] = param;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    returnValue = MethodtoInvoke.Invoke(mainWindow, Parameter);
                  
                }
                else
                    returnValue = MethodtoInvoke.Invoke(mainWindow, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception InvokeMethod  \n" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Currently, I am able to invoke Parentform instance methods which are available in MainForm.

**Helper.cs**

```
public class Helper
      {
        private async void OpenParentForm(string MethodName)
        {
        ReflectionHelper.InvokeMethod(static Instance of MainForm, MethodName, null);
        }
        private async void ShowChildForm(string MethodName)
        {
        ReflectionHelper.InvokeMethod(Instance of frmParent, MethodName, null);
        }
        private async void ChildMethod(string MethodName)
        {
        Invoke ChildMethod ???
        }
      }
```

**CallingClass.cs**

```
 class CallingClass
        {
            public async Task<bool> CallMethod(string MethodName)
            {
                switch (MethodName)
                {
                    case "OpenParentForm":
                        Helper.OpenParentForm(MethodName);
                        break;
                    case "ShowChildForm":
                        Helper.ShowChildForm(MethodName);
                        break;
                    case "ChildMethod":
                        Helper.ChildMethod(MethodName);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
```

I want to invoke  MainForm>>frmParent>>[Instance of ChildForm in using block of frmParent.cs].ChildMethod()

Comment: Please never write: `try { ... } catch { }`. It is a horrific way of swallowing errors without meaningfully dealing with them. I also dislike `try { ... } catch (Exception ex) { ... }`. Those are lazy ways to "handle" exceptions. You should always code to avoid exceptions where possible and then only handle ***specific*** exceptions that you can handle in a ***meaningful*** way.

Comment: It's also unclear on what form `ChildMethod()` is on. You say `[Instance of ChildForm in using block].ChildMethod()`, but you also say `static Instance of MainForm` which seems to be a contradiction.

Comment: @Enigmativity I Just removed the Logger logic in exception for better readability of the question.

Comment: The question hasn't been updated.

Comment: @Enigmativity I just updated

Comment: Can you deal with my "unclear" issue please?

Comment: @Enigmativity ChildMethod() is on ChildForm.cs and Childform Instance is available under using block of frmParent.cs

Comment: Yes, but why have you got `static Instance of MainForm`? That makes it sound like you're invoking from that class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240465/discussion-between-maahi-and-enigmativity).

Comment: Please show the code that calls `Helper.ChildMethod()`.

Comment: You're making a rabbit hole. If this code is really production code then you are going to cause yourself serious maintenance issues. Please show the code that calls `CallingClass.CallMethod(string MethodName)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the instance of an already opened form using `Application.OpenForms["FormName"]`

Example:

```
ChildForm frmChild = Application.OpenForms["ChildForm"] as ChildForm;
```

Then you can pass that instance in your `InvokeMethod` as a parameter to call your `ChildForm` Methods.

```
ReflectionHelper.InvokeMethod(frmChild , MethodName, null);
```

Your `Helper.cs` file will look like:

```
public class Helper
{
        .....
        .....
        .....
        .....
        private async void ChildMethod(string MethodName)
        {
            ChildForm frmChild = Application.OpenForms["ChildForm"] as ChildForm;
            if(frmChild!=null)
              ReflectionHelper.InvokeMethod(frmChild , MethodName, null);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Sandeep, this code is working with a small change in my ShowChildForm() method. Because (frmChild.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) is a blocking call. I was unable to invoke other methods. So I make ShowDialog Async. Now its working fine. Thanks again.

Comment: @Maahi - You really have an awful architecture. It's convoluted and unnecessary. I'm just trying to help you to find a better solution and to discourage future readers from going down this path. I'm not commenting in any way other than to try to help.

Comment: @Enigmative The question was not about better architecture. The code in this question is just to represent the problem, not the actual implementation. I can't put the complete code which used various design patterns. Even StackOverflow suggests keeping the question short. You are talking about try-catch block, Architecture, etc., etc. but not given the solution.

Comment: @Maahi - I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve. You've given us a keyhole view into the issue. Until I see the bigger picture I can't give you a solution.